# Determine the sign (positive or negative) of an integral with the fractional Laplacian

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, inequalities

Let $u,v:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and $\phi: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R_+$ be smooth bounded functions. Assume also $\phi' \ge 0$. Assume that $u(0) - v(0) = 0$ and that $0$ is a strict global minimum of $u-v$. Let us assume $D_\epsilon = \{x: u(x)-v(x) < \epsilon\} \subset B_1(0)$. Under these assumptions, is it possible to determine the sign of $$\int_{D_\epsilon} \phi \, \Big([(-\Delta)^s](u-v)\Big) $$
that is  $$\int_{D_\epsilon} \phi(x) \left(\int_{\mathbb R}  \frac{u(x+z) -v(x+z) -v(x)-u(x)}{|z|^{1+2s}} dz\right) dx  $$
positive or negative?

Note that, if we had $$\int_{D_\epsilon} \phi(x)\partial_x(u-v)dx$$ instead of the fractional Laplacian, I would compute
$$\int_{D_\epsilon} \phi(x)\partial_x(u-v)dx =  \int_{D_\epsilon} \phi(x)\partial_x(\min\{u-v-\epsilon,0\}) dx = \int_{B_1} \phi(x)\partial_x(\min\{u-v-\epsilon,0\}) dx\ge 0$$
(becasue the function is continuous and identically zero on a neighborhood of $\partial B_1$).

Comment: Is that supposed to have $\psi[(-\Delta)^{s}]$?

Comment: @Buzz I've edited the notation hoping to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sign can be arbitrary already for $s = 1$. In this case we can take $u(x) - v(x) = 1 - \cos (\pi x)$ for $|x| \leqslant 1$ and $u(x) - v(x) = 2$ when $|x| > 1$, and $\epsilon = 2$. Then the integral becomes
$$ I := \int_{-1}^1 \phi(x) (-2 \pi^2 \cos(\pi x)) dx = -2 \pi^2 \int_{-1}^1 \phi(x) \cos(\pi x) dx .$$
Now it is easy to cook up $\phi$ so that the above expression is either positive or negative. To be specific:

- If $\phi(x) = 0$ for $x < \tfrac12$ and $\phi(x) > 0$ for $x > \tfrac12$, then clearly $I > 0$.
- On the other hand, if $\phi(x) = 0$ for $x < \tfrac12$ and $\phi(x) = 1$ for $x > 0$, then it is easy to see that $I < 0$.

---

The same construction will work for $s \in (0, 1)$ sufficiently close to $1$. A similar argument (but with a less explicit $u - v$) should also work for a general $s \in (0, 1)$, but I did not attempt to work out the details.

Comment: It's very strange: it works out when we replace the Laplacian by a single derivative (according to the computation in the question). Am I missing something?

Comment: That's right, but why do you find it strange? There are many differences between $\partial_x$ and $\Delta$, one of them being the fact that if $\check f(x) = f(-x)$, then $\partial_x \check f(x) = -\partial_x f(x)$, while $\Delta \check f(x) = \Delta f(x)$ (without a minus sign). This means that if the answer to the original problem was positive, then it would also work for *decreasing* $\phi$, and thus, by linearity, for *arbitrary* (non-negative) $\phi$. (By the way, this alone shows that the answer has to be negative.)

Comment: Thanks! I see. Would it make a difference if I considered instead of the fractional Laplacian the following slightly different nonlocal operator $$A_s[f] = \int_{B_\epsilon(0)} \frac{f(x+z)-f(x) - \nabla f(x)z}{|z|^{1+2s}}dz$$? Or what if I picked $\phi \equiv$ constant?

Comment: I do not think replacing $(-\Delta)^s$ by $A_s$ changes the picture in any way — the argument from my previous comment remains valid, right?

Comment: Regarding $\phi$ constant: for $s = 1$, the answer is clearly "yes". For $s \in (0, 1)$ I guess the answer is still "yes", but this is not so straightforward.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I would be curious too about the variant with $\phi \equiv 1$. If we had $\int_{\mathbb R} (-\Delta)^s (u-v)$, I guess it would be $\equiv 0$ regardless of $u$ and $v$. But if we have $\int_{D_\epsilon} (-\Delta)^s (u-v)$ how would one prove it?

Comment: The integral over $\mathbb R$ is indeed zero, as long as we have some minimal regularity of $u - v$. For the integral over $D_\epsilon$, formally one can use the identity $$\int_{\mathbb R} f (-\Delta)^s g = c \int_{\mathbb R} \int_{\mathbb R} (f(x)-f(y))(g(x)-g(y)) |x-y|^{-1-2s}dxdy$$ with $f = u - v$ and $g = \mathbb 1_{D_\epsilon}$, but when $s \geqslant \tfrac12$ one has to be careful here, because $g$ is not regular enough in order to apply this formula directly and one has to approximate with more regular functions. But this is a different question, I suppose.

Comment: Actually, the $s < 1/2$ case is exactly what I'd like to consider most. But, in that case, from your last line how does it follow that $....\equiv 0$?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what do you mean by "last line" and the elipsis in "$....=0$".

Comment: I mean how does one get $\int_{\mathbb R}  (u-v)(-\Delta)^s 1_{D_\epsilon} \equiv 0$ for $s < 1/2$?

Comment: Also, by the way, if $\epsilon$ is chosen small enough, wouldn't we be able to get a sign on the original integral by the continuity of $(-\Delta)^s(u-v)$?

Comment: Write $f = u - v$ and $g = \mathbb 1_{D_\epsilon}$. Then $(f(x) - f(y))(g(x) - g(y)) \leqslant 0$ for all $x$ and $y$, and so $$\begin{aligned}\int_{D_\epsilon} (-\Delta)^s f(x) dx & = \int_{\mathbb R} g(x) (-\Delta)^s f(x) dx \\& = c \int_{\mathbb R} \int_{\mathbb R} (f(x) - f(y)) (g(x) - g(y)) |x - y|^{-1-2s} dx dy \leqslant 0.\end{aligned}$$ No chance this will be equal to zero, unless $f$ is constant.

Comment: Regarding your last comment: yes, but this $\epsilon$ will generally depend on $f$, will it not?